# First non-null value per group in a table with many columns

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql

The problem of finding first non-null values is discussed extensively on SO, but all the solutions are problematic for some reason, maybe due to my inexperience with PostgreSQL. I have the following structure in the table:

```
group           submitted   num1  num2  num3  str1  str2  str3 ...
   32  14:04:21 4.5.2020.      2     1  Null  Null  Null  Null
   32  13:01:23 4.5.2020.   Null     1     0   abc   def  Null
   37  15:01:44 3.2.2020.      2  Null     0  Null  Null   aar
   37  03:04:21 2.1.2020.   Null     1     0   abc   def  Null
   37  23:04:00 1.1.2020.      2  Null     0   trt   def   abg
   ...
```

The desired outcome of the example above is:

```
group  num1  num2  num3  str1  str2  str3 ...
   32     2     1     0   abc   def  Null
   37     2     1     0   abc   def   aar
...
```

There are 40+ columns, and performance is important. I need one row per group containing the latest non-null value in time, or first non-null in the above (sorted) dataset. What I tried so far is:

1) Sort by submitted, groupby group and then I couldn't find an aggregation function that finds the first non-null. Is there a way to crete a custom aggregtion function in some way?

2) Using the solutions with window functions:

```
...
first_value(education) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE ORDER BY submitted WHEN education IS NOT NULL THEN submitted END) as education,
...
```

are very slow (hundreds of times slower than groupby with MAX) and I feel since all the tables have the same partition that this shouldn't be repeated for each column. Is there a way to perform the partition on the whole table and then look for the first value per column?

3) Some solutions mention ROWNUM. The problem with this (and most solutions) is that after the first sort and partition, there is no need to go through all the values in the column.

The kind of solution I am hoping for is the analogue of pandas [first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a trick, which is to use `array_agg()` and remove nulls.  That would be:

```
select groupid,
       (array_remove(array_agg(num1 order by submitted desc), null))[1] as num1,
       (array_remove(array_agg(num2 order by submitted desc), null))[1] as num2,
       . . .
from t
group by groupid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=121f3743931a7c962846f4e494e6093b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Your awesomeness knows no bounds. Now I wonder how to upvote this answer, because I wasted ages reading up on this!